Azure App Gateway: change public IP zero downtime?
Our app's DNS record points to a public IP handled by an Azure Application Gateway.
We need to switch over to a different public IP with zero downtime.
It would seem that each App Gateway can only handle a single public IP, see ApplicationGatewayFrontendIPConfiguration. Is that correct? Or is there a way to temporarily have the App Gateway serve two public IPs?
If not possible to serve two IPs, just updating that IP in-place and immediately updating the DNS record would cause a temporary outage during the DNS caching period - right?
So, would a zero downtime solution require temporarily adding a second Application Gateway (identical to the existing one, just different public IP), then cutting over the DNS record, then (after a few days) cleaning up the old Application Gateway? Or is there an easier solution?

Yes, you are correct that each Azure Application Gateway can only handle a single public IP address. If you update the IP address in-place and immediately update the DNS record, there will be a temporary outage during the DNS caching period. To achieve zero downtime, you can create a second Application Gateway with the new public IP address, and then cut over the DNS record to point to the new Application Gateway. After a few days, you can delete the old Application Gateway.


Manage a public IP address with an Azure Application Gateway
Application gateway components
Application Gateway frontend IP address configuration


As discussed, to achieve zero downtime when switching the public IP address of an Azure Application Gateway, you can create a second Application Gateway with the new public IP address, update the DNS record to point to the new Application Gateway, and then decommission the old Application Gateway after ensuring traffic has fully transitioned.
Create a Second Application Gateway

Create a new public IP address that will be used by the new Application Gateway.

az network public-ip create --resource-group <your-resource-group> --name <new-public-ip-name> --allocation-method Static --sku Standard



Create a new Application Gateway with the same settings as the current one but assign it the new public IP address.

az network application-gateway create \
  --name <new-app-gateway-name> \
  --location <your-location> \
  --resource-group <your-resource-group> \
  --vnet-name <your-vnet-name> \
  --subnet <your-subnet-name> \
  --public-ip-address <new-public-ip-name> \
  --sku Standard_v2 \
  --capacity <capacity> \
  --frontend-port 80 \
  --http-settings-cookie-based-affinity Disabled \
  --http-settings-port 80 \
  --http-settings-protocol Http \
  --routing-rule-type Basic



Ensure the new Application Gateway mirrors the configuration of the existing one, including backend pools, routing rules, health probes, and SSL certificates. Before making any changes, reduce the TTL (Time to Live) for the DNS records to minimize caching and speed up propagation. Set the TTL to a low value (e.g., 60 seconds).


az network dns record-set a update --resource-group <your-dns-resource-group> --zone-name <your-domain> --name <your-dns-record> --ttl 60


Change the DNS record to point to the new public IP address of the second Application Gateway.

az network dns record-set a add-record --resource-group <your-dns-resource-group> --zone-name <your-domain> --record-set-name <your-dns-record> --ipv4-address <new-public-ip-address>



Use tools like nslookup or online DNS checkers to verify that the DNS changes are propagating correctly and clients are resolving to the new IP address.

Done. Finally monitor and Decommission the Old Application Gateway
az network application-gateway delete --resource-group <your-resource-group> --name <old-app-gateway-name>

Reference:

Manage a public IP address with an Azure Application Gateway
Application gateway components
Application Gateway frontend IP address configuration


appreciate this detailed response, thank you!
